# How can i add mail notification action when auto update failed

Tags: install4j

I want to add failure mail notification when auto update failed case. 
What is the right place to keep this action ?

please suggest.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To react to a rollback in case of failure, add a "Run script" action to the "Startup" node of the updater and configure its "Optional Rollback Script" property with the desired action.